# Is there a quick way to convert a varchar(8) binary sequence to an integer in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, binary, type-conversion, integer, varchar

I have a `DECLARE @binarySequence varchar(8) = '00000000';`. I use STUFF to manually change the bit value in each index. That code is not relevant for this question though.Once I change all the necessary bits, then `SELECT @binarySequence;` returns `'01001001'`. Is there a way for me to change that so that it returns the decimal representation (73) of that binary sequence without looping through each char?
All advice is welcome as well as any answers/questions
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Signed Magnitude Representation Binaries

This is something I wrote a couple of years ago. It uses a Tally to split the value into its individual characters, and then aggregates each value at their relevant `POWER` to get the final result:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SignedBinaryToDec] (@Binary varchar(64)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@Binary)-1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
    SELECT SUM(SS.C * POWER(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),2),T.I-1)) *
           CASE LEFT(@Binary,1) WHEN 0 THEN 1
                                WHEN 1 THEN -1
           END AS Dec
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Binary),T.I,1)))SS(C)
    WHERE @Binary NOT LIKE '%[^0-1]%';
GO

SELECT Dec
FROM dbo.SignedBinaryToDec('01001001');
```

---

### How this works

The above is a inline-table value function. This means that it returns a dataset, rather than a scalar value, and you refer to it in the `FROM`. The reason for this is that multi-line scalar functions can perform quite poorly. In SQL Server 2019+ it can inline user defined scalar functions, however, I'm not sure if such a query would be. As such I wouldn't want to take the chance of using it, when an iTVF with set based logic will be performant.

Let's break this into a few steps:

#### The Tally

The first part of the query you'll see is the 2 Common Table Expressions (CTEs); `N` and `Tally`. `N` literally just contains 4 rows with the value `NULL`. Why 4? I'll explain later. Why `NULL`? Well, it can be any arbitrary value, I just use `NULL` as its values are meaningless.

Next we have the CTE `Tally`. Firstly you'll note that it references `N` in the `FROM` 3 times; this means that `N` is `CROSS JOIN`ed (using the old ANSI-89 syntax, yes) to itself 3 times, resulting in (at most) 64 rows, `4^3 = 64`, which is (you'll notice) the length of the parameter, `varchar(64)`. That is why I used 4 `NULL` values.

In the `SELECT` I limit the number of rows to be returned to the length of the `varchar` value `-1`. `-1` because the binary value is signed, so the first digit in the string won't be used to determine the aggregate value (done later), but to denote if the value is positive or negative.

Finally we have `ROW_NUMBER` which unsurprisingly gives each row an ascending number, starting from `1`. `(SELECT NULL)` is in the `ORDER BY` here as we (again) need some arbitrary value.

If we were to stop at here, with your value, this would result in a data set containing 7 rows, with the values `1` to `7`. You can test this with the below

```sql
DECLARE @Binary varchar(64) = '01001001';

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@Binary)-1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally;
```

#### The outer SELECT

We'll go to the `FROM` again first. Obviously `FROM Tally` returns the rows from the CTE `Tally`, which we just discussed. Next we have the `CROSS APPLY` to a `VALUES` table construct. This returns each individual character for the `varchar` on a separate row. Note we `REVERSE` the values as you the lowest denomimated is on the right in numbers.  If you were to return the results for your value from just the `FROM` you would end up with the following data set:

| I | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 |

> ***Note***
> *`REVERSE` was not in my original solution, not sure how I missed that, but as the value was a palindrome we "lucked" out.*

The `WHERE` is there to stop the query trying to process any invalid values. For example, if you were to input `'01001a01'` or `'013240101'` the function would not return a result.

Now the `SELECT`. We'll break this down.

- `POWER(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),2),T.I-1)`
  There a few bits here. Firstly we take the `int` value `2` and convert it specifically to a `decimal(2,0)`. Then we have `POWER` which "does what it says on the tin"; it takes the first value and puts it to the power of the second.
  So, for the first row (in the above data set), that would be `POWER(2,1-1)` which is `1`. Then we have `POWER(2,2-1)`, `POWER(2,3-1)`, `POWER(2,4-1)`, which are `2`, `4`, and `8` respectively. As you can tell, these are your binary numbers.
- `SUM(SS.C * POWER(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),2),T.I-1))`
  Here we taking the expression before and multiplying it by the digit from the `varchar` and then aggregate those values. For your example, this means you have an expression that resolves into something like:
  `SUM((1*1) + (0*2) + (0*4) + (1*8) + (0*16) + (0*32) + (1*64)) = SUM(1 + 0 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 0 + 64) = SUM(1 + 8 + 64) = 73`
- The `CASE` expression
  This literally just inspects the left most character of the `varchar`. If it's `0` it multiplies the value in the previous step by `1` (unchanging the value), and if it's `1` then by `-1`, making the value negative. This is an implementation of [Signed magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation).
  If you are using [One's Compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) or [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) this will not give the expected value for negative values. (You are, however, clearly not using [Negative Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base)).

---

### Other methods

#### Unsigned Binary

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UnsignedBinaryToDec] (@Binary varchar(64)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@Binary)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
    SELECT SUM(SS.C * POWER(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),2),T.I-1)) AS Dec
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Binary),T.I,1)))SS(C)
    WHERE @Binary NOT LIKE '%[^0-1]%';
GO
```

This uses all the same logic as before, so doesn't require further details.

#### One's Complement

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[OnesComplementBinaryToDec] (@Binary varchar(64)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@Binary)-1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
    SELECT 
           SUM(BW.B * POWER(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),2),T.I-1)) *
           CASE LEFT(@Binary,1) WHEN 0 THEN 1
                                WHEN 1 THEN -1
           END AS Dec           
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(bit,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Binary),T.I,1))))SS(C)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE LEFT(@Binary,1) WHEN 0 THEN SS.C ELSE ~SS.C END))BW(B)
    WHERE @Binary NOT LIKE '%[^0-1]%';
GO
```

Much of the same here. You'll note, however, the additional `CROSS APPLY`. `~` is a [Bitwise NOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This means that `1` becomes `0` and `0` becomes `1`, so when the first digit is a `1` (denoting the value is negative), then the Bitwise NOT is applied.

### Two's Complement

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TwosComplementBinaryToDec] (@Binary varchar(64)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@Binary)-1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
    SELECT 
           SUM(BW.B * POWER(CONVERT(decimal(2,0),2),T.I-1)) *
           CASE LEFT(@Binary,1) WHEN 0 THEN 1
                                WHEN 1 THEN -1
           END - LEFT(@Binary,1) AS Dec
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(bit,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Binary),T.I,1))))SS(C)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE LEFT(@Binary,1) WHEN 0 THEN SS.C ELSE ~SS.C END))BW(B)
    WHERE @Binary NOT LIKE '%[^0-1]%';
```

Identical to One's apart from that you subtract the left most digit.

### Example results:

```sql
SELECT V.Binary AS B,
       U.[Dec] AS U,
       S.[Dec] AS S,
       [1s].[Dec] AS [1s],
       [2s].[Dec] AS [2s]
FROM (VALUES('0000'),('0001'),('0010'),('0011'),
            ('0100'),('0101'),('0110'),('0111'),
            ('1000'),('1001'),('1010'),('1011'),
            ('1100'),('1101'),('1110'),('1111'))V(Binary)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.UnsignedBinaryToDec(Binary) U
     CROSS APPLY dbo.SignedBinaryToDec(Binary) S
     CROSS APPLY dbo.OnesComplementBinaryToDec(Binary) [1s]
     CROSS APPLY dbo.TwosComplementBinaryToDec(Binary) [2s]
ORDER BY V.Binary;
```

| Binary | Unsigned | Signed | One's | Two's |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0001 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0010 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 0011 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 0100 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 0101 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 0110 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 0111 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 1000 | 8 | 0* | -7 | -8 |
| 1001 | 9 | -1 | -6 | -7 |
| 1010 | 10 | -2 | -5 | -6 |
| 1011 | 11 | -3 | -4 | -5 |
| 1100 | 12 | -4 | -3 | -4 |
| 1101 | 13 | -5 | -2 | -3 |
| 1110 | 14 | -6 | -1 | -2 |
| 1111 | 15 | -7 | 0* | -1 |

<sup>* Represents `-0`</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! What if I wanted to only return the decimal of the binary sequence passed in instead of a table?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, @CodingGoneWrong . The above `SELECT` would only return a single value, the `decimal` value for the Binary `varchar` you passed in (in your example, `73`).

Comment: I figured it out don't worry now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, @CodingGoneWrong . If it is helpful and/or answers the question, please do consider upvoting the answer and/or marking it as a the solution so that future readers know it was helpful as well.

Comment: I have too low reputation for it to show up but I have upvoted it!

Comment: @Stu, I suspect they did, you need 15 reputation to up vote publically. They have 13.

Comment: Ah right, not asked a question on SO myself. At the time of the previous msg there was only one +1 and it was mine lol

Comment: 1. Why does your function return a table instead of an int?
2. What does your code on line 6? What ```VALUES``` is it picking up from? and Why do you have that many ```(NULL)``` parenthesis?
3. What is the Tally variable for and what does the select statement mean/ do? I do not understand the ```ROW_NUMBER()``` and the ```OVER``` keywords as well as the why you ```ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)``` and why the ```FROM``` has ```N N1, N N2, N N3```
4. How does the sum work and what does the ```CROSS APPLY``` do?
Most of the keywords I do not understand. As well as why you put the last ```WHERE```.

Comment: I hope that all helps, @CodingGoneWrong .

Comment: BRO. I am so amazed at the quality of explanation you gave. No questions are left for me to ask!!! Well freaking done!

Comment: Just don't forget that I've assumed Signed magnitude representation here, @CodingGoneWrong . If you aren't using that, perhaps you're using unsigned binary values, or Two's Compliment, this won't give the results you expect.

Comment: I am using unsigned values. The resulting binary sequence is a full on 128 to 1 8 bit number. So min value =0 and max value = 255

Comment: I'll dump the other solutions in there as well then, @CodingGoneWrong .

Comment: Unsigned, One's, and Two's complements added, @CodingGoneWrong .

Comment: I just got onto SO since Friday. I am so happy with the solutions you have put up and thank you alot for your time! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For now I have managed to create a function that turns a varchar(8) bit sequence into an integer.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION  BinarySequenceToInt
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @BinarySequence varchar(64)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    
    DECLARE @bitIndex int = 1;
    DECLARE @SequenceLength int = LEN(@BinarySequence)
    DECLARE @powerInversionNumber int = @SequenceLength;
    DECLARE @BitSequenceNumber int = 0;
    
    WHILE @bitIndex <= @SequenceLength
        BEGIN
            IF(SUBSTRING(@BinarySequence , @bitIndex,1) = '1')
                BEGIN
                    SET @BitSequenceNumber = @BitSequenceNumber + POWER(2,@powerInversionNumber-@bitIndex);
                END
            SET @bitIndex += 1;
        END
    return @BitSequenceNumber

END
GO
```

Which returns 73 if I pass it '01001000'.
I know that instead of hard coding 8 I could take the length of the varchar passed so I will work on that.

Comment: FYI, this will be significantly slower than the solution I provided. This is a Multi-line Scalar function, which are known to sometimes perform poorly, and (worse) it uses a `WHILE`. SQL is a set based language, so it excels at set based logic (like in my answer), but as expected it therefore performs poorly at iterative logic, such as your `WHILE`.

Comment: Does it return a signed or unsigned result? Have you tried converting 64-bit values with your function? `@BinarySequence varchar(64)` and `@BitSequenceNumber int` may not play well.

Comment: @HABO I haven't no, do you think that ```int```  will be too small of a range for a 64 bit varchar? Either way for my usecase I do not need more than 8 bits.

Comment: @Larnu the reason I made the function I made is because I am having a hard time understanding your code. I am not that advanced in SQL performance stuff etc. I use a lot of while loops to loop through varchars in my different projects. Perhaps if you can explain your solution I can not only improve the current function but also my other functions. Basically the stuff you have used in your suggestion are too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: @CodingGoneWrong if you leave a comment under my answer on what parts you're not sure on, I'll be happy to elaborate on them by editting it.

Comment: Lovely working on that now @Larnu.

Comment: As I alluded to, however, loops are one of the *last* things you should be using in SQL. I would honestly say I can probably count the number of times you should be using them on one hand. Getting used to set based thinking isn't quick, I freely admit that (it takes a lot of us time), but once you get there you can get so much more out of SQL. :)