# Convert a binary representation of a number stored as VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, type-conversion

I'm working with a SQL Server database which has a column containing a binary number.

However, the binary number is stored as a `VARCHAR`.

I need to convert the `VARCHAR` into its numerical representation so I can do some further calculations.

For example I want to convert the string `"0010"` to the numeric value `2`.

However trying to `CAST` the string as an `int` gives me the value `10` instead.

Any suggestions for how I can make this conversion in SQL?

Comment: Posssible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952833/how-to-convert-binary-to-integer-in-sql-server.

Comment: What is your sql server version, how long can these numbers be and who thought storing binary numbers as strings was a good idea?

Comment: @siggemannen - SQL Server 2012, and the database is read only, provided by a third party software vendor. Numbers are all exactly 52 characters (it's a "visual" representation of a year, with a "1" for the week(s) of interest).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a quick way to convert a varchar(8) binary sequence to an integer in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622034/is-there-a-quick-way-to-convert-a-varchar8-binary-sequence-to-an-integer-in-t)

Comment: @paulopadopalos if it is a 52 character string representing weeks of the year, why do you want to convert into to an int? '1000' presumably represents the 4th week of the year, but you're asking for it to return the number 8.  I just want to confirm this is the correct approach for what you're doing.

Comment: @hcaelxxam - A single row may have multiple weeks with a "1". I want to use bitwise calculations to check whether different rows have any weeks in common.

Comment: @paulopadopalos - To be sure, your strings ALWAYS have exactly 52 characters, and the following string would represent weeks 51, 4, and 1, Correct? '0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001'

Comment: Signed/unsigned? Big/little endian?

Answer (score 0):

The following iTVF will do the trick for this question as further explained by the OP in the comments associated with the question above.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UnmaskWeeks
        (@WeekMask VARCHAR(64))
/*********************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a "Week Mask" of exactly 52 characters where a "1" is a "Week of Interest" and a "0" is
 not and "Week 1" is the right-most character, return the "Weeks of Interest" as a list in a
 single column.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Usage Examples:
--===== Single value usage.
     -- The following example returns a column called "WeekNumber" containing the values of
     -- 51, 4, and 1.  Remember, the right-most character is "Week 1".
 SELECT WeekNumber 
   FROM dbo.UnmaskWeeks ('0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001')
;
--===== Usage for a column in a table.
     -- The RowPK is the column that uniquely identifies each row, which is necessary because
     -- this function will return multiple rows if multiple weeks are contain in the mask for
     -- any given row.
 SELECT st.RowPK, uw.WeekNumber
   FROM dbo.SomeTable st
  OUTER APPLY dbo.UnmaskWeeks (st.SomeWeekMaskColumn) uw
;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Programmer Notes:
 1. This is a high-performance iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function) that will work in all
    versions of SQL Server from 2005 and up.
 2. The week numbers are return in the default of occurance from left to right in the string.
    In other words, they will be numerically descending.  If some other order is required,
    do that externally of the this function.
 3. If the length of @WeekMask is not exactly 52 characters, a row will not be returned. To
    have a RowPK return with a NULL for the WeekNumber, you must use OUTER APPLY as in the
    the Example Usage section above or no row will be returned, which may be the desired
    result.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 04 Jan 2024 - Jeff Moden
                      - Initial creation and unit test.
 Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759453/convert-a-binary-representation-of-a-number-stored-as-varchar-to-int
*********************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN WITH 
    E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))E0(N)) --Up to 8 rows
   ,Tally(N) AS (--==== This is a super small version of Itzik Ben-Gan's GETNUMS() FUNCTION
                 SELECT TOP(52)
                        N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                  FROM E1 a,E1 b --1 to 8^2 or 64 rows max
                )
 SELECT WeekNumber = 53-t.N
   FROM Tally t
  WHERE LEN(@WeekMask) = 52 --Return nothing if the week mask isn't the correct length
    AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(@WeekMask,t.N,1)) = 49 --ASCII trick for a little extra performance
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a using a user-defined function with the following logic:

1. Pad the input string to 64 bits.
2. Replace each 4-bit value with the equivalent hex digit.
3. Convert the resulting hex string to BIGINT using built-in conversion functions.

```
-- Function to convert a string of 1-64 bits to an integer (bigint) value.
-- Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759453/
-- Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952833/
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertBitStringToBigInt(@BitString VARCHAR(65))
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Validate: non-null, non-blank, lenght <= 64 and only binary.
    -- (The input parameter is slightly oversized to detect oversized input.)
    IF (
        @BitString IS NULL
        OR @BitString = ''
        OR LEN(@BitString) > 64
        OR @BitString LIKE '%[^01]%'
    )
        RETURN NULL

    -- Pad input on left to 64 characters
    DECLARE @PaddedString VARCHAR(100)
        = REPLICATE('0', 64 - LEN(@BitString)) + @BitString

    -- Insert delimiters between each 4-bit group
    DECLARE @DelimitedString VARCHAR(100)
        = CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString,  1, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString,  5, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString,  9, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 13, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 17, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 21, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 25, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 29, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 33, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 37, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 41, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 45, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 49, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 53, 4), '_',
            SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 57, 4), '_', SUBSTRING(@PaddedString, 61, 4)
        )

    -- Convert each 4-bit group to a hex digit and remove the group delimiters
    DECLARE @HexSTring VARCHAR(100) =
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            @DelimitedString
            , '0000', '0'), '0001', '1'), '0010', '2'), '0011', '3')
            , '0100', '4'), '0101', '5'), '0110', '6'), '0111', '7')
            , '1000', '8'), '1001', '9'), '1010', 'a'), '1011', 'b')
            , '1100', 'c'), '1101', 'd'), '1110', 'e'), '1111', 'f')
            , '_', '')

    -- Convert hex to BINARY (raw byte string) type and then to BIGINT
    RETURN CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @HexSTring, 2))
END
```

Sample results:

| BitString | BigIntResult | Binary8 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 | 2 | 0x0000000000000002 |
| 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010 | 2 | 0x0000000000000002 |
| 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001 | 1125899906842633 | 0x0004000000000009 |
| 0 | 0 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 1 | 1 | 0x0000000000000001 |
| 11111111 | 255 | 0x00000000000000FF |
| 1111111111111111 | 65535 | 0x000000000000FFFF |
| 01111111111111111111111111111111 | 2147483647 | 0x000000007FFFFFFF |
| 11111111111111111111111111111111 | 4294967295 | 0x00000000FFFFFFFF |
| 0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 | 9223372036854775807 | 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
| 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 | -1 | 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
| 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | -9223372036854775808 | 0x8000000000000000 |
| 1111111011011100101110101001100001110110010101000011001000010000 | -81985529216486896 | 0xFEDCBA9876543210 |
| 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 | *null* | *null* |
| 012 | *null* | *null* |
|  | *null* | *null* |
| 00000110010110110001110101101110100 | 853076852 | 0x0000000032D8EB74 |
| 11000111010110111010 | 816570 | 0x00000000000C75BA |
| 00000000000011000111010110111010 | 816570 | 0x00000000000C75BA |
| 11111111111100111000101001000110 | 4294150726 | 0x00000000FFF38A46 |
| 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100111000101001000110 | -816570 | 0xFFFFFFFFFFF38A46 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CO8fDFIC) for a demo.

Comment: The above answer have been revised to use a simpler bit string to hex to `BINARY(8)` to `BIGINT` conversion that works across all recent SQL Server versions.